# Not able to access singleton object inside XCTestCase Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, cocoa-touch, xctestcase

I am writing a XCTestCase for some timer validation. My timer runs once every 30 seconds and I keep track of the run count in a singleton object `MySessionObject` where `MySessionObject` is a macro pointing to `[MySession sharedSession]`.

Problem is, when I am executing my test, I am always getting `0` in `MySessionObject.timerCount`. However, when I run it via application target, this gets set correctly.

Any clue as what I am missing here to load singleton? My assumption was it should have set with application launch by my test target.

```
NSInteger timerCountsToTest = 2;

// Adding a delay to counter network operation
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:(30 * timerCountsToTest) + 2];

XCTAssertEqual(timerCountsToTest, MySessionObject.timerCount, "Timer did not work properly.");
```

Comment: I believe this is something to do with workspace. Test workspace is different than application workspace.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Please take a look at my answer. I worked it out this way. In case you have a better solution, please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I, eventually, had to put a hidden `UITxtField` in the app and set the timer counter as text in that text field and then fetch it from UI Script. In case someone has a better approach, please advise.